# How to change DropdownMenuItem's background color for selected item

Tags: flutter, background-color, selecteditem, dropdownbutton

I use DropdownButtonFormField. Is there a way to change background color of the selected DropdownMenuItem? Please see the attached screen.[image: Selected Item has grey color]

It's always gray.

I tried all the options of the DropdownButtonFormField, nothing works.

Comment: Where is the code I need to look at

Comment: It isn't possible with the default `DropDownButtonFormField` you would have to create your own `DropDownButtonFormField` extending `FormField` and modify `_DropdownMenuItemButton` so that it changes colors depending on whether it is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @raw-chicken. I checked the sources and found that **DropdownButtonFormField** uses **InkWell**. So the best way I found is to wrap **DropdownButtonFormField** with the **Theme** widget and set **focusColor**:

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    focusColor: Colors.amber,
  ),
  child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
    value: 'Item 2',
    onChanged: (value) {},
    items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'].map((item) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: item,
        child: Text(item),
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
)
```